# Rename file under sub-directory in bash

Tags: bash, scripts, rename

I would like to know how to change the name of a txt file inside a directory.

I know that I can  `mv test123 test456`, but that only changes the name in the current directory.  What if I want to change the name of a txt file inside `/home/folder1/`?

Answer (score 2):

Run the following:

```
mv /home/folder1/test123 /home/folder1/test456
```

Comment: it just gives me No such file or directory error...

Comment: What is the name of your file, and what folder is it in specifically?

Comment: Right now i made it work by doing this 

#!/bin/bash
ls *.txt > Scripttextfil1.txt
mkdir modul2
cp Scripttextfil1.txt modul2
mv  modul2/Scripttextfil1.txt nyttextfil.txt
cp nyttextfil.txt modul2
rm nyttextfil.txt

but this is not "clean scripting" i need to just change the  file name without having to copy more or remove more documents.. i hope u understand

Comment: What i want is to change the name of the file inside modul2 from scripttextfil1.txt to nyttextfil.txt

Comment: Okay, I *think* I'm starting to catch you now.  :)  So run `mv modul2/scripttextfil1.txt modul2/nyttextfil.txt`.   Make sure you get spelling and capitalization right.

Comment: No problem.  My pleasure.  Basically, you have to put the folder name *both* in front of the file you are moving *and* in front of the file you are renaming to.

Comment: May i ask one more thing! how do i work with pipes and grep to make ls show all files ending in txt from my home dir

Comment: I use the `find` command: `sudo find ~/ -name *.txt`

Comment: Or if you just want the ones straight in your home directory, you can use `ls *.txt`.